# Not defined error for some variables in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using the following code in codepen and facing this issue, 
for conctact i am getting the following error

Why is it giving error for contact and not for name?

How can i solve this ?

```
angular.js:13550 ReferenceError: contact is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (pen.js:8)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4665)
    at R.instance (angular.js:10115)
    at n (angular.js:9033)
    at g (angular.js:8397)
    at g (angular.js:8400)
    at angular.js:8277
    at angular.js:1751
    at n.$eval (angular.js:17229)
    at n.$apply (angular.js:17329)
```

Here is js file

```
var app = angular.module("crud", []);

app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [3, 4, 5, 34, 34];
    debugger;
    $scope.name = name;
    $scope.contact = contact;
    $scope.obj = {
        name: $scope.name,
        contact: $scope.contact
    };
    console.log($scope.obj);
}]);
```

Here is the HTML file that i am using.

```
<body ng-app="crud">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">       
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in data track by $index">
          <td>{{x}}</td>
          <td>{{$index}}</td>
        </tr> 
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

PLEASE answer these questions

1. Why is it failing at contact and not at name ?
2. Contact is number data, what should i give the default value to it ?

Comment: what you are getting in contact  that you are assigning to `$scope.contact`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  $scope.name = name;
  $scope.contact = contact;
```

Its throwing error for contact is because there is no global contact variable in your app, but if you go to console and type name.. there is a global variable name which equals `""` so it does not throw error.

If you replace `$scope.name` with any other variable, it would throw error for that. Its all because name is global which equals empty string.

A fiddle where it throws for `age` instead of `contact`.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/o6a54Lw5/1/

A fiddle where it throws for `contact` instead of `name`.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/o6a54Lw5/2/

Now in the second fiddle if you go to console and type `name`, you would see its declared `global`.

Comment: Thanks. and this one -- Contact is number data, what should i give the default value to it ?

Comment: You can give anything depending your need of app, $scope.contact = 0; or what ever value you want to keep it...

Answer (score 2):

Do not give name as `name` for a global variable as it denotes [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) because,

> window.name gets/sets the name of the window.

For that reason, its never undefined and so the `$scope` will accept it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue,

```
 $scope.contact = contact;
```

you have not defined contact and name anywhere.

[`Working APP`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/abmo7rs0/1/)

Comment: I have not defined name as well.

Comment: Please read the question again and try to answer exactly what i asked.

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha Check the sample app